# installation of xgboost python mac

Tags: python, linux, data-science, xgboost

I'm having trouble installing and getting running with xgboost for mac.  I must be missing something obvious as I know there are tutorials out there, I just can't make sense of where I am going wrong.  I'm not as familiar with this process of installing on Linux and all the various path importances and what-not.

What I should do next?  Maybe all the technical speak is giving me a bit of struggle.

What I've done so far:

```
cd /home/myname/xgboost/python-package
ls   ## I can see things like setup.py and setup_pip.py and a folder called xgboost.
python setup.py --user
```

This gives me an error "cannot find exgboost library in candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in the root path?

I then back out and try to go to

```
cd /home/myname/xgboost/
```

and then type

```
sh build.sh
```

I then get an error with:

> unrecognized command line option -std=c++11'  make: *** build/learner error 1

None of this makes much sense to me an is pretty confusing.  Can someone explain things in a step by step way or where am I going wrong? In R I just do install.packages'xgboost' and I'm done.

Comment: Can you tell us what version of `gcc` you have? (`gcc -v`) If `gcc` doesn't recognize C++11, that means what you're trying to install isn't compatible with the version of `gcc` on your system.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XGBoostLibraryNotFound: Cannot find XGBoost Library in the candidate path, did you install compilers and run build.sh in root path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43327020/xgboostlibrarynotfound-cannot-find-xgboost-library-in-the-candidate-path-did-y)